# Determine the environment of a project by its name in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to determine a URL based on the environment of a project.
The URL depends on the designed environments

```java
public String getBaseUrlByNamespace(String namespace) {
    if(namespace.contains("-")) {           
        
        ArrayList<String> envTOTO = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("-wp", "-dmz"));
        ArrayList<String> envJACKO = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("-d", "-d2", "-d3", "-i", "-i2", "-i3", "-k", "-k2", "-k3", "-r", "-q", "-dmz-q"));
        
        for (int indexEnv = 0; indexEnv < envTOTO.size(); indexEnv++) {
            if(namespace.contains(envTOTO.get(indexEnv))) {
                return this.getTOTOBaseUrl();
            }               
        }           
        
        for (int indexEnv = 0; indexEnv < envJACKO.size(); indexEnv++) {
            if(namespace.contains(envJACKO.get(indexEnv))) {
                return this.getJAKOBaseUrl();
            }               
        }       

    } else {
        return this.getTOTOBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

I need it to work with this for example :

```
System.out.println("TOTO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi"));
System.out.println("JAKO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-d"));
System.out.println("JAKO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-d-gag"));
System.out.println("JAKO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-i2"));
System.out.println("JAKO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-q"));
System.out.println("JAKO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-dmz-q")); //this one fails
System.out.println("TOTO=" + toto.getBaseUrlByNamespace("titi-dmz"));
```

Let me know if you have something that can work

Thanks !